# print dictionary and string objects in same statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, sequence

I have code:

```
coin = {'Bug Out Bag': ['quarter', 0.25, 10000], 'small': ['quarters', 0.25, 10]}
for coin in sorted(coins_in_the_bag, key=coins_in_the_bag.get):
        print(str('bag:' + coin + 'coin: ' + coin[0] + 'value: ' + (coin[1] * coin[2]) ))
```

When I run this, I get:

```
    print(str('bag:' + coin + 'coin: ' + coin[0] + 'value: ' + (coin[1] * coin[2
]) ))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

How can I do this, so that I get an output of (as I'm trying to achieve with my code):

```
bag: small coin: quarter 2.50
bag: Bug Out Bag coin: quarter 2500.0
```

**Sorting**
I am looking to sort this based on the totalvalue of coin[1] * coin[2] for each coin.

Thank you.

Comment: which version of python are you using ?

Comment: It would be better, if you told us, based on what you wanted the sorting, is it on the key or which element of the list?

Comment: Ive added it to my question.

Comment: Total or multiplication?

Comment: Multiplication of the values

Comment: Ok..Just updated on your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> coins_in_the_bag = {'Bug Out Bag': ['quarter', 0.25, 10000], 'small': ['quarters', 0.25, 10]}
>>> for k,v in sorted(coins_in_the_bag.items(), reverse=True):
    print ('bag: {0} coin {1} value {2}'.format(k, v[0], v[1]*v[2]))


bag: small coin quarters value 2.5
bag: Bug Out Bag coin quarter value 2500.0
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to sort the dictionary items with respect to the multiplication of Second and Third elements of each list, here is one way:

```
>>> sorted(coins_in_the_bag.items(), key=lambda s: s[1][1]*s[1][2])
[('small', ['quarters', 0.25, 10]), ('Bug Out Bag', ['quarter', 0.25, 10000])]
```

Comment: This gives me an error of:     for k,v in sorted(coins.items(), reverse=True):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: `coins` is a list or dictionary?

Comment: I got it. Its for k,v in sorted(coins_in_the_bag.items(), reverse=True): instead of for k,v in sorted(coins.items(), reverse=True):  . Please post to your answer, and ill mark you as accepted :) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
coin = {'Bug Out Bag': ['quarter', 0.25, 10000], 'small': ['quarters', 0.25, 10]}

for c in sorted(coin,key=coin.get):
    print('bag: {0} coin {1} value {2}'.format(c, coin[c][0], float(coin[c][1])*float(coin[c][2])))
```

Comment: the order is reversed